Quick way to test if LDAP is correct?
In my company we use LDAP in order to use SSO (Single-Sign-On) to access our ERP software.
We have realized that that are multiple users with invalid LDAP, and they are therefore unable to use SSO because the entered LDAP doesn't match the one from ActiveDirectory (AD).
I am looking for a way to quickly check wether the entered LDAP is correct or not.
Is there a way in OpenEdge to achieve that?
I assume that I'd have to connect to our AD somehow. Does anyone have experience in this matter?
Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Can you provide more info on how you authenticate users. how are the users invalid ? On linux I use ldapsearch to list all users matching a ldap query. if an active directory user is not listed I know something is wrong with that users's definition.
